# Copy a user defined variable into string

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to copy a user defined variable such as this:

```
print('Enter date required e.g. 2021-08-14 : ')
inputdate = input()
```

into a string such as this:

```
dest_dir = "N:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-08/inputdate".
```

How can I concatenate the `inputdate` variable into the `dest_dir` definition?

Comment: You can either use `fstring` or `pathlib`.

Comment: Do you want to parse the input date into the "2021/2021-08" part? Please give more complete examples of what you want. (Also, in general we can tell that any question involving `input()` is often homework ;-) -- this is fine, but especially in those cases it's useful to tell us what you've tried.)

Comment: If I entered `2021-09-01`, do you want the result to be `'n:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-09/2021-09-01'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is always going to be in the format "%Y-%m-%d", you can use `str.split()` with f-strings:

```
print('Enter date required e.g. 2021-08-14 : ')
inputdate = input()
year,month,day = inputdate.split("-")

dest_dir = f"N:/RAW Ingest Backup/{year}/{year}-{month}/{inputdate}"
'N:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-08/2021-08-14'

>>> dest_dir #with inputdate '2021-08-14'
'N:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-08/2021-08-14'
```

#### Edit

If you want to validate that the user input is a valid date, use:

```
from datetime import datetime
print('Enter date required e.g. 2021-08-14 : ')
inputdate = input()
date = datetime.strptime(inputdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
dest_dir = f"N:/RAW Ingest Backup/{date.year}/{date.strftime('%Y-%m')}/{inputdate}"

>>> dest_dir #with input 2021-08-14
'N:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-08/2021-08-14'
```

Comment: `split` can only verify the lexical structure; it can't verify that you entered a valid date. Use `datetime.strptime` to do both.

Comment: @chepner - Sure, if OP wants to validate input!

Comment: That's practically a given. I'm not just talking about accidentally creating a date like September 31, 2021. I'm talking about something like `year, month, day = "foo-bar-baz".split("-")`.

Comment: This solution works fine: "Assuming your input is always going to be in the format "%Y-%m-%d", you can use str.split() with f-strings:"

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like that ?

```py
input_date = input("Enter a date: ")
destination_dir = rf"N:/RAW Ingest Backup/2021/2021-08/{input_date}"
print(f"Location is : {destination_dir}")
```

If i'm wrong i really don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Thanks to you all for your advice. This is the solution to my problem
#works like a dream:

import shutil
import os

print('Enter date required e.g. 2021-08-14 : ')
inputdate = input()
year,month,day = inputdate.split("-")

# path to source directory.
src_dir = f"L:/Master_Images/{year}/{year}-{month}/{inputdate}"
print(f"Source Location is : {src_dir}")

# path to destination directory. **** Destination directory should not exist .
dest_dir = f"N:/RAW Ingest Backup/{year}/{year}-{month}/{inputdate}"
print(f"Destination Location is : {dest_dir}")

print('Collating all files from Source Directory')
files = os.listdir(src_dir)

print('Copying all files to Destination Directory')
# copy entire contents to the destination directory
shutil.copytree(src_dir, dest_dir)
```